# How to get filename without extension from file path in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I get the filename from a file path in Ruby?

For example if I have a path of `"C:\projects\blah.dll"` and I just want the "blah".

Is there a `LastIndexOf` method in Ruby?

Comment: Keep in mind that there's nothing special about a dot followed by some (three, perhaps) characters.  They're part of the name of the file.  Some fringe operating systems think there's something special about that part of a filename, but you shouldn't fall into that trap.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new('/opt/local/bin/ruby').basename
# => #<Pathname:ruby>
```

I haven't been a Windows user in a long time, but the Pathname rdoc says it has no issues with directory-name separators on Windows.

Comment: I don't know why this is the #1 ranked answer when File.basename doesn't require an extra 'require' of 'pathname'.

Comment: Class `pathname` works with local pathnames while `File` always assumes Unix pathnames (difference is path and drive separators which are used in MS Windows, for example)

Comment: @korch: You should probably show the different behaviour of `Pathname.new("C:/some/path").basename` to  `File.basename("C:/some/path")` (see comment from nimrodm).

Comment: File doesn't assume it's *nix. The IO docs specifically say that Ruby is OS independent when it comes to pathname separators. "Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible...."

Comment: Despite being accepted by the OP, this answer doesn't actually respond to the OP's question. See Jonathan Lonowski's and Arup Rakshit's answers.

Comment: The extension is present if there is one. The answer is wrong.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 605):

Try [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/File.html#M000803)

> Returns the last component of the filename given in file_name, which must be formed using forward slashes (``/’’) regardless of the separator used on the local file system. If suffix is given and present at the end of file_name, it is removed.
>
> ```
> File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb")          #=> "ruby.rb"
> File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb", ".rb")   #=> "ruby"
> ```

In your case:

```
File.basename("C:\\projects\\blah.dll", ".dll")  #=> "blah"
```

Comment: With Linux and Ruby 1.8 I try `Pathname.new("some/path/to/my.file").basename` and get `my.file/` :'(

Comment: More generically, `File.basename("C:\\projects\\blah.dll", ".*")  #=> "blah"`

Comment: The answer should be add the solution of @kelloti which is better.

Comment: @kelloti: What about `/my/file.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 58):

In case the extension is not known (it needs the / separator):

```
irb(main):024:0> f = 'C:\foobar\blah.txt'.gsub("\\","/")
=> "C:/foobar/blah.txt"
irb(main):027:0> File.basename(f,File.extname(f))
=> "blah"
```

Comment: File.basename() is the answer!

Answer (score 28):

[Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374345/2767755) answered perfectly, but there is something that none of the answers mentioned here. Instead of [`File::extname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-extname), you can directly use a `'.*'` to get the file name.

```
File.basename("C:\\projects\\blah.dll", ".*") # => "C:\\projects\\blah"
```

But, if you want to get the base file name of *any specific extension files*, then you need to use `File::extname`, otherwise not.

Answer (score 20):

Try this code

Use [`extname`](http://apidock.com/ruby/File/extname/class)

```
 File.basename("a/b/d/test.rb", File.extname("a/b/d/test.rb")) #=> "test"
```

Answer (score 7):

Jonathon's answer is better, but to let you know `somelist[-1]` is one of the `LastIndexOf` notations available.

As krusty.ar mentioned `somelist.last` apparently is too.

```
irb(main):003:0* f = 'C:\\path\\file.txt'
irb(main):007:0> f.split('\\')
=> ["C:", "path", "file.txt"]
irb(main):008:0> f.split('\\')[-1]
=> "file.txt"
```

Comment: problem with that is that you need to know if it's a backslash or forwardslash

Answer (score 3):

Note that double quotes strings escape \'s.

```
'C:\projects\blah.dll'.split('\\').last
```

Comment: Treats it purely as a string, rather than as a path, makes the code less portable.

Comment: This is way more complexity than is needed, and is Windows-specific. You can just `File.basename`. And, like some of the other answers, does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use `Pathname` with `.*`

```
path = Pathname.new('/home/motine/myname.dll')
path.basename('.*') # => "myname"
```

`basename` actually returns a `Pathname` instance. If you want to force a string, you can call `to_s` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ENV variables, `scan` combined with this little regex (which finds the last but one word, a dot, then the last word of the string) will put the file's name into 'filename':

```
filename = ENV['SCRIPT_NAME'].scan(/\w+\.\w+$/)
```

Obviously, you can use `scan` and the regex on any path name that includes the filename, and `__FILE__` is the obvious choice:

```
__FILE__.scan(/\w+\.\w+$/)
```

Answer (score -5):

You can get directory path to current script with:

```
File.dirname __FILE__
```

Comment: The question was not about the path, it was about the **file name**. "How can I get the **file name** from a file path in Ruby?"

Comment: That would be: `File.basename __FILE__`