# Get file name and extension in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I'm working on a program to download a video from YouTube, convert it to MP3 and create a directory structure for the files.

My code is:

```
FileUtils.cd("#{$musicdir}/#{$folder}") do
  YoutubeDlhelperLibs::Downloader.get($url)
  if File.exists?('*.mp4')
    puts 'Remove unneeded tempfile'
    Dir['*.mp4'].each do |waste|
      File.delete(waste)
    end
  else
    puts 'Temporary file already deleted'
  end

  Dir['*.m4a'].each do |rip|
    rip.to_s
    rip.split
    puts 'Inside the function'
    puts rip
  end

end
```

The first one goes to the already created music folder. Inside that I'm executing `get`. After that I have two files in the directory: "xyz.mp4" and "xyz.m4a".

I would like to fetch the filename without the extension so I can handle both files differently.

I'm using an array, but an array for just one match sounds crazy for me.

Has anyone another idea?

Comment: Don't use `$globals` like you are. They are a very strong hint you don't understand variable scoping and are relying on globals to "cheat". They are code-smell and lead to misery and pain.

Comment: Also `rip.to_s` and `rip.split` do nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get filename without extension from file path in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374326/how-to-get-filename-without-extension-from-file-path-in-ruby)

Answer (score 418, accepted):

You can use the following functions for your purpose:

```
path = "/path/to/xyz.mp4"

File.basename(path)         # => "xyz.mp4"
File.extname(path)          # => ".mp4"
File.basename(path, ".mp4") # => "xyz"
File.basename(path, ".*")   # => "xyz"
File.dirname(path)          # => "/path/to"
```

Comment: Note that `extn` is the string `".mp4"` [or even the string `".*"`](http://phrogz.net/filename-without-extension-ruby).

Comment: Thanks. The problem in this case is, that i don't know the filename on that place. I just know that two files existing. One .mp4 and one .m4a. How can i get that filenames?

Comment: @saigkill use ".*", wildcard, as Phrogz said if you don't know/care what the extension is.

Comment: There's at least 60 times so far I wanted to kiss the person who wrote this