# Rails 4 - is there a way to compress big images to make them load faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, caching, assets

In a Rails 4 app, we have some big images on our homepage (the dimensions are like 2400px on width) and naturally, their loading is quite slow.

What are the options to speed up loading them? One way is to decrease their quality => their size => faster loading.

But is there a Rails way how to pre-cache/compress them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Rails way" to do this. This is a problem no matter what framework/language you're using and is best solved with a [content delivery network (aka CDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

Answer (score 1):

One good practice is to run all images through [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) before the final commit into your codebase. This tool does *lossless* compression, meaning the pixels don't change and it still reduced file size.

That's not a "Rails" solution but it is the best way I know to reduce filesize (About 10% usually) without sacrificing even any quality at all.

Answer (score 1):

To give googler's some perspective on this, here are the facts:

- There is no core Rails function to achieve this with *assets*
- There *are* ways to achieve it with uploaded images

The problem you have is that since assets are manually added to Rails, there's no [pre-processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_pre-processing) you can do. If you wanted to optimize images for different environments, you'd have to create different resolutions of the images, and then use some logic to define them:

```
- assets 
-- images
--- backgrounds
---- original.jpg
---- medium.jpg
---- small.jpg
```

You'd then be able to use a helper method to define the image you want:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def size size, image
      assets_path("#{File.basename(image)}/#{size.to_s}#{File.extname(image)}")
   end
end
```

Ref: [Get file name and extension in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793180/get-file-name-and-extension)

This would allow you to call:

```
<%= image_tag size(:original, "backgrounds.jpg") %>
```

If you wanted to make this dynamic, you'd have to use CSS and set a background image, with corresponding `@media` queries assigning the different images as you need.

---

If you're talking about *uploaded* images, you'll be best looking into how [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) does it:

> **ImageMagick** must be installed and Paperclip must have access to it. To ensure that it does, on your command line, run which convert (one of the ImageMagick utilities).

Paperclip uses ImageMagick to split images into different sizes. These are then stored in the `/public/system` folder, and is why you call `@model.image.url(:original)` when you're using it.

What I described above is basically how Paperclip works, excepting automatically using ImageMagick to make different image sizes