# How to get the name of file without extension?

Tags: ruby, string, split

Lets say I have this `string ="C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb"` and Im trying to split only "Filename" from it.

I tried string.split.last and it returns "Filename.rb", I tried dropping the ".rb" but drop method isnt working for me. is there any other methods I can use?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. `string.split.last` returns `"C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb"`.

Comment: I meant to write `string.split("/").last`

Comment: `File#basename` would be best, but this should work: `"C:/EFI/Ulta/File...name.rb"[/(?:.*\/)?(.+)\.?/,1] => "File...name"`. If the filename is preceded by a forward slash, the non-capture group `(?:.*\/)` gobbles up all characters up to an including the last forward slash. `?` allows for the possibility that the filename is at the start of the string. The capture group (#1), `(.+)`, then consumes all characters up to the last dot, if there  is at least one dot. `?` allows for the possibility that there is no filename suffix. `,1` retrieves the contents of capture group 1.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = "C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb"
File.basename(f,File.extname(f))
#=> "Filename"
```

[How to get filename without extension from file path in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374326/get-filename-from-file-path-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have any *specific* preferences about the file *extension*, you can use the below trick. It works with 100% confidence.

```
string ="C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb"
File.basename(string, ".*") # => "Filename"
```

The only *difference* with [*djsmentya*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25509039/2767755) answers is, I didn't use [`File::extname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-extname) method. At least as per OP's example, I don't see any need to use `::extname` method.

Comment: This was down-voted. I would be very interested in knowing why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with files you can use [basename](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-basename)

```
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb")          #=> "ruby.rb"
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb", ".rb")   #=> "ruby"
```

Otherwise if it's just a string:

```
'C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb'.split('/').last.split('.').first
```

**EDIT**

If you want a generic solution working based on string manipulation only, you can use this approach:

```
path = 'C:\file\path\to\file.rb'
match = match = path.match(/^.*(\\|\/)(.+(\\|\/))*(.+)(\.(.+))*$/)
filename = match.values_at(match.size-2)
```

This will work with unix and windows path's and filename with a more than one dot.

Comment: The edge case here is `"my.long.filename.with.full.stops.rb"`

Comment: @AFaderDarkly I've created another solution solving the issue you spotted.

Comment: That regex burns my eyes! Also `path.match` returns nil, which fails on the `match.size` step. Sure it's just a simple typo but I'm not going to debug that regex... ;)

Comment: @AFaderDarkly the example is working now.

Comment: I believe you may have fallen into the trap I fell in to, and failed to catch filenames without an extension. They fail with the same error on match.size.

Comment: Impressive regex skillz however.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb'

def filename_from_path(path)
  parts = path.split('/').last.split('.')
  (parts.size > 1 ? parts[0..-2] : parts).join('.')
end

filename_from_path(path)
```

should do it.

Examples:

```
filename_from_path('C:/EFI/Ulta/Filename.rb')
# => "Filename" 

filename_from_path('C:/EFI/Ulta/Filen.ame.rb')
# => "Filen.ame" 

filename_from_path('C:/EFI/Ulta/Filenamerb')
# => "Filenamerb"
```

Although the correct way to do it is probably with File.basename as per other answers.

Comment: And, indeed, fixed. :)

Comment: Although when File does this for you in a well tested and tried and true fashion (with extra benefits) then this becomes merely an exercise in string manipulation.

Comment: I love exercises in string manipulation.