# Is there a more elegant way to substring?

Tags: ruby, string, filenames

Here is my code

```
file_name = Dir['path/xml/test/*.txt']
file_name.to_s # => ["path/xml/test/test.txt"]
```

I want to return:

```
"test"
```

I can do it with the code below:

```
file_name = Dir['path/xml/test/*.txt']
file_name.to_s[15,60].gsub(/.txt["]/,"").gsub(/]/,"")
```

But it is not very elegant. Is there a more elegant way to just return the filename without `.txt` and `[]`?

Comment: Since `Dir[]` is giving you an array, you should not cast it to a string. Instead, call `.first` or maybe `.pop` on it (or many other possibilities for accessing the array element depending on your needs) to get the first element, then you can use [these suggestions to with `File.basename()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374326/how-to-get-filename-without-extension-from-file-path-in-ruby) to retrieve the part of the filename you want.

Comment: Do you expect that your `Dir[]` will return multiple files? If so, do you want to get the names of all of them?

Comment: Yes I want to return multiple names so I can match the file name to an element in an xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
File.basename(Dir['path/xml/test/*.txt'].first, ".txt")
# => "test"
```

To do it for all files,

```
Dir['path/xml/test/*.txt'].map{|e| File.basename(e, ".txt")}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this for all the files in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Also possible in case there are more files ...

```
Dir[ 'path/name/*.txt' ].map { | e | 
  File.basename( e ).split(".").first 
}
```

Comment: It's already known that they're all `.txt`, so you can avoid the split if you just use `File.basename(e, '.txt')`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That's true but I like to access the parts of a string with `first` and `last`