# How to obtain basename in ruby from the given file path in unix or windows format?

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to parse a basename in ruby a from file path which I get as input. Unix format works fine on Linux.

```
File.basename("/tmp/text.txt")
```

return "text.txt".
However, when I get input in windows format:

```
File.basename("C:\Users\john\note.txt")
```

or

```
File.basename("C:\\Users\\john\\note.txt")
```

"C:Usersjohn\note.txt" is the output (note that `\n` is a new line there), but I didn't get "note.txt".

Is there some nice solution in ruby/rails?

Solution:

```
"C:\\test\\note.txt".split(/\\|\//).last
=> "note.txt"
"/tmp/test/note.txt".split(/\\|\//).last
=> "note.txt"
```

If the Linux file name doesn't contain `\`, it will work.

Comment: Note: `"C:\U".chars #=> ["C", ":", "U"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Further note "\note" is treated as new line character (`\n`)  ote.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes, while how Windows expresses things, are just a giant nuisance. Within a double-quoted string they have special meaning so you either need to do:

```
File.basename("C:\\Users\\john\\note.txt")
```

Or use single quotes that avoid the issue:

```
File.basename('C:\Users\john\note.txt')
```

Or use regular slashes which aren't impacted:

```
File.basename("C:/Users/john/note.txt")
```

Where Ruby does the mapping for you to the platform-specific path separator.

Comment: The first two didn't work for me on macos. Because of `File::SEPARATOR`, I assume. So, short of running this code on windows. the caller has to convert the slashes as a pre-processing step. :shrug:

Comment: It seems that the only way is substitute ` and \` to / and then parse it as Unix file path. Or mess up with File::ALT_SEPARATOR. Anyway, it will change Unix file names like `/tmp/test\file.txt` :(

Answer (score 3):

Try `pathname`:

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new('C:\Users\john\note.txt').basename
# => #<Pathname:note.txt>
```

[Pathname docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html)

Ref [How to get filename without extension from file path in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374326/how-to-get-filename-without-extension-from-file-path-in-ruby)

Comment: @CarySwoveland what do you mean?

Comment: The OP used double quotes without escaping the backslash.

Comment: This does not seem to work in linux using 2.6.1 `Pathname.new('C:\Users\john\note.txt').basename #=> #<Pathname:C:\Users\john\note.txt>`

Comment: @engineersmnky It won't work in Linux because Linux doesn't treat the backslash the same way as Windows does.

Comment: @tadman my point was more that it is unlikely a rails server is running over IIS so this may not be a viable option

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in same way as `File.basename` in Linux ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that you have a problem with your code. I think you have a problem with your test.

Ruby also uses the backslash character for [escape sequences](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/syntax/literals.rdoc#strings) in strings, so when you type the String literal `"C:\Users\john\note.txt"`, Ruby sees the first two backslashes as invalid escape sequences, and so ignores the escape character. `\n` refers to a newline. So, to Ruby, this literal is the same as `"C:Usersjohn\note.txt"`. There aren't any file separators in that sequence, since \n is a newline, not a backslash followed by the letter *n*, so File.basename just returns it as it receives it.

If you ask for user input in either a graphical user interface (GUI) or command line interface (CLI), the user entering input needn't worry about Ruby String escape sequences; those only matter for String literals directly in the code. Try it! Type `gets` into [IRB](https://github.com/ruby/irb) or [Pry](https://pryrepl.org/), and type or copy a file path, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and see how Ruby displays it as a String literal.

On Windows, Ruby accepts paths given using both "/" (File::SEPARATOR) and "\\" ([File::ALT_SEPARATOR](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#ALT_SEPARATOR)), so you don't need to worry about conversion unless you are displaying it to the user.

Comment: You are right with `gets` -> `"C:\\Users\\john\\note.txt\n"`. However, in Linux Ruby/Rails `File` nor `Pathname` cannot parse it.

Comment: @malmed: I'm not on Windows right now, so I can't check, but I'm fairly sure that both File and Pathname should handle "C:\\Users\\john\\note.txt" just fine. I suspect it is the trailing newline (\n) that is causing your problem. Use String#chop.

Comment: I'm also not on Windows (but I receive both formats of a path). I don't doubt, that "C:\\Users\\john\\note.txt" is parsed fine on Windows.

Comment: @malmed Are you saying that you want a user to input a file path into a web application, and then have your app manipulate that path? I'm having a hard time imagining a use case for that. Obviously, you can just use String#split.